# When do I have to dispose my context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, telerik-mvc

I have my project using MVC and I've got my controller that instantiates a service, the service manages the repository and in the repository makes the CRUD operations. The problem is, once a I populate my grid control (Telerik) with the data from my service, if I make an update and I refresh the data, it appears the old data instead of the new one. I think it's a problem of the persistance of my context variable that requires to be disposed/instantiated but not quite sure about when and where (the Unit Of Work variable is located at the service).

```
    <HttpPost()>
    <GridAction()>
    Function Edit(id As Integer, name As String, clientNo As String, image As String, unit As String) As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim org = Me._orgService.GetOrgById(id)

            With org
                .orgNAME = name
                .orgCLIENTNO = clientNo
                .orgIMAGE = image
                .orgUNIT = unit
            End With

            TryUpdateModel(org)
            Me._orgService.EditOrg(org)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Log the error 
            ModelState.AddModelError("", MS_UNABLE_SAVE_CHANGES)
            Response.StatusCode = 500
            Return Content(String.Join("", (From state In ModelState Select state).SelectMany(Function(s) s.Value.Errors).Select(Function(e) e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()))
        End Try

        Return View(New GridModel(All()))

    End Function
```

This is the service

```
    Public Sub EditOrg(org As hdmtORG) Implements IOrgService.EditOrg
        Me._context.OrgRepository.Edit(org)
        Save()
    End Sub
```

This is the repository (generic)

```
    Public Overridable Sub Update(entity As TEntity) Implements IEntityRepository(Of TEntity).Edit
        Me._objectSet.Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified)
    End Sub
```

Any idea?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `<OutputCache(Duration:=0)> _`

```
<OutputCache(Duration:=0)>
<HttpPost()>
    <GridAction()>
    Function Edit(id As Integer, name As String, clientNo As String, image As String, unit As String) As ActionResult
```

Comment: Sorry Jitendra but after a bit of testing it doesn't work, if I refresh the data it shows the old/new value and not just the new one. Any other idea?

Comment: Can you please tell me in which browser you are testing? Except IE, other browsers does not cache data instead you explicitly write the code for that.